# Couchdb installation on Windows Server

Tags: couchdb

By default Couchdb listen at port : 5984 - when you deploy it on Windows Server. do you need to open up that port but how would you make it secure?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is more about server security and networks than CouchDb. But I will try to answer. There's two options I can think of:

(1) Configure your CouchDb server for HTTPS and **only** open port 6984 (or whatever port you are going to use for SSL).

(2) Or (better) setup a reverse proxy (I use Nginx) on the Windows server and configure it to accept HTTPS traffic on port 443 as normal, and redirect connections from 443 to CouchDb's 5984 port. Only open port 443 to external connections.

There are many articles out there on setting up Nginx as a reverse proxy. [This one](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-nginx-with-ssl-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-jenkins) from DigitalOcean assumes the application behind the reverse proxy is Jenkins, but the setup for CouchDb is similar. DigitalOcean have some very good articles on server setup so it is worth looking through their community documents.

**NB** make sure the first thing you do after installing CouchDb is set an administrator username and password so only you can change the configuration and databases.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to open the port 5984 on Windows if you want to access it remotely. You will also need to set the `bind_address` to `0.0.0.0`